# JSoup web-scraping: How to select each value

Tags: android, html, css-selectors, jsoup

I'm currently trying to get some values from a [website](https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/GPU_mega_page.html) with Jsoup for my android application.

Basically, I wanted to extract these values:[image]
so that in the code, the model name should go to gpuModel variable, prices goes to gpuPrice and so on for every single Graphic card. and then I would store them in firebase using this code:

```
public void addToDatabase(String model, int price, int rating, double value, 
double bench) {
        Map<String, Object> docData = new HashMap<>();
        docData.put("model", model);
        docData.put("rating", rating);
        docData.put("bench", bench);
        docData.put("value", value);
        docData.put("price", price);

        db.collection("gpu").document(model).set(docData);
    }
```

This is the HTML code for each GPU:[image]

i am currently trying to extract only the gpu model name to keep it simple (in the end i want to extract all the other values too), this is my current web scraping code:

```
public void webScrape(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/GPU_mega_page.html").get();
                Elements gpus = doc.select("[id^=gpu]");

                for (Element i : gpus) {
                    Elements gpuModel = i.select("tr td:nth-child(2)");
                    String gpuName = gpuModel.text().replace("/", "");
                    addToDatabase(gpuName, 12,12,12,12);
                }
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

going by my logic, this should select all the GPU, and then in the for loop, it would extract only the card's name. set the gpuName to whatever was extracted and push it to the database.

But instead, I got this in my database:

[image: firebase]

It extracted the GPU name, but also all the other unwanted fields (including the prices, value, test date, etc).

so my question is, how do i select each value separately? all the examples i found on the internet was done with a very simple website where each value has their own ID so I can't really learn from them.

If there's anything i should provide, please do tell me.

simple code representation of what i want:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(the url).get();
Elements gpus = doc.select(all gpu);

for (each gpu in all gpus) {
      gpuName = gpu.select(name);
      gpuPrice = gpu.select(price);
      gpuValue = gpu.select(value);
      gpuPower = gpu.select(power);
      addToDatabase(gpuName, gpuPrice, gpuPower, gpuValue);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `a:nth-child(2)` as the model name selector inside your `run` method:

```
Elements gpuModel = i.select("a:nth-child(2)");
```

Comment: oh wow it works! thank you for that, but i have to ask, how do you extract the other values? i can't seem to understand css selector since there's so many variations of HTML documents. any good tips?

Comment: for example, how come the `tr td:nth-child(2)` extracts all the other value? i thought it would i can't wrap my head around the logic

Comment: this is my guess, would `td:nth-child(8)` extracts the test date? (in my example, aug 2016)

Comment: You are right about the test date. The best way to figure out the right selector will be to use your browser's developer tools (F12) and use the 'inspect' function to choose an element and view it's selector.

Comment: oh boy i did not know that existed, thank you so much!!!

oh and one more thing if you don't mind, since gpu model name is located inside the first td (td:nth-child(1)), how come your code can afford to not select the first td and still able to get the model name?

Comment: does html treats all the "a" inside each id as a whole? meaning if i typed "a:nth-child(3)" it would extract the third "a" from the top, regardless of which td it's located on?

Comment: These are intersting questions. Maybe indeed the answer is because of the `a` tag.

Comment: tested it and yeah not mentioning the td is fine, I can simply a:nth-child(3) to extract the price, but not on all gpu for some reason, so i stick with the usual method (mentioning the td first). Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, you really really helped me on this, especially that view selector tool you mentioned. anything I can do for you? maybe share your stuff or something?

Comment: You are welcome :) I'm here to help other people, the same way I get help from this site, so no need for anything else - enjoy!